# Создание правильного цикла в событии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую в проекте плагин `air-datepicker`.
В нем есть собственные [описанные события](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html#events).

Есть массив дат, которые мы должны заблокировать, пытаюсь сделать это через функцию рисования ячеек при открытии календаря, запуская в нем цикл,
но при моем цикле событие обрабатывает только первый элемент массива, до других не доходит.
Как я понимаю из-за `return`.

Подскажите, как правильно прописать цикл, дабы блокировались все дни?

```js
let LastResult = $('.Datex').length;
let disabledDays = [0, 6];
var arr = [];
$('#Date').datepicker({ //образаемся к календарю
  onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) { //вызываем функцию отрисовки ячеек
    // запускаем цикл 
    for (i = 0; i < LastResult; ++i) {
      arr[i] = $('.Datex').eq(i).text();
      // получаем из элемента массива день
      var test = arr[i].split('.');
      d = +test[0];
      m = +test[1] - 1;
      var y = +test[2];
      
      // если рисуется день и он равен D то мы его блокируем
      if (cellType == 'day' && date.getDate() == d) {
        return {
          disabled: true
        }
      } else
        // блокируем выходные
        if (cellType == 'day') {
          var day = date.getDay(),
            isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
          return {
            disabled: isDisabled
          }
        }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<input id="Date" type="text" name="calendar" class="datepicker-here" data-range="true" data-toggleselected="false" data-multiple-dates-separator=" - " placeholder="нажмите для выбора">

<div id="InfoСoincidence" class="OrderPanel panel panel-default">
  <div class="Datex">21.11.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">22.11.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">23.11.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">23.09.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">2.09.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">13.09.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">14.09.2017</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Gic0/pen/gGrVbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно один раз преобразовать даты в приемлемый для лёгкой проверки формат и при рендере просто проверять наличие:

```js
// Преобразуем даты в объект вида: {2017: {9: [2, 13, ...]}}
let disabledDays = Array.from($('.Datex')).reduce((acc, e) => {
  let date = new Date(e.innerHTML.split('.').reverse().join('-'));
  let [year, month, day] = [date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate()];
  
  if(!(year in acc))
    acc[year] = {};
  if(!(month in acc[year]))
    acc[year][month] = [];
    
  acc[year][month].push(day);
  
  return acc;
}, {});

$('#Date').datepicker({
  onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
    if(cellType !== 'day') return; // Не работаем с чем-либо кроме дней
    let [year, month, day] = [date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate()]; // Отрисовываемые данные
    
    if((year in disabledDays) && (month in disabledDays[year]) && (disabledDays[year][month].includes(day))){ // Простые условия проверки
      return {
        disabled: true
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<input id="Date" type="text" name="calendar" class="datepicker-here" data-range="true" data-toggleselected="false" data-multiple-dates-separator=" - " placeholder="нажмите для выбора">

<div id="InfoСoincidence" class="OrderPanel panel panel-default">
  <div class="Datex">21.11.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">22.11.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">23.11.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">23.09.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">2.09.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">13.09.2017</div>
  <div class="Datex">14.09.2017</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в `return`, как вы думаете, а в том, что переменная `d` всегда у вас равна 21.

Лучше перед вызовом `datepicker` определить массив дней/дат которые недоступны, а уже внутри функции `onRenderCell` проверять - есть ли в этом массиве значение или нет.